# Chamar a controller via javascript ou ajax e inserir na tabela asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, entity-framework-6

Como eu posso pegar um item do ul li passar o value(id) dele para minha controller e la inserir esse value na tabela?

eu já tenho a lista esse trecho de código abaixo ja funciona eu consigo adicionar itens na lista e ver text e value:

```
            $("#addPeca").click(function () {
            //Váriavel para checar se já existe na lista
            var jaExisteNaLista = false;
            $(".listasDasPecas").show();

            $('#ListPeca li').each(function () {
                haveSomeLi = true;
                var current = $(this).text();
                if (current == $("#Pecas option:selected").text()) {
                    jaExisteNaLista = true;
                }
            });

            if (!jaExisteNaLista) {
                $("#ListPeca").append("<li>" + $("#Pecas option:selected").text() + "<input type='checkbox' name='chkPeca' id='chkPeca' class='chkPeca' checked='checked' value='" + $("#Pecas option:selected").val() + "'></li>");
            } else {
                alert("Peca Já inserida!");
            }
        });
```

Agora quero pegar o que vier desse li e quando clicar em add já chama minha controller "addPeca" e faz a insert na tabela de acordo com id que veioda li.
então fiz minha controller assim até agora, mas estou meio perdido:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Detalhes")]
public ActionResult AddPecas(int id)
{

    using (Db db = new Db())
    {

        var lstPeca = Request.Form["chkPeca"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lstPeca))
        {
            //cria array de peças vindo do form
            int[] splTags = lstPeca.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();

            if (splTags.Count() > 0)
            {
                //verifica id
                var PostPeca = db.Pecas.Where(p => splTags.Contains(p.Id));

                ConsertoDetalhes consDetalhe = new ConsertoDetalhes();

                // Add para ConsertoDetalhe
                foreach (var item in PostPeca)
                {
                    consDetalhe.ConsertoId = consertoId;
                    consDetalhe.ClienteId = clientId;
                    consDetalhe.PecasId = item.Id;//pecaID
                    consDetalhe.FuncionarioId = funcId;
                    consDetalhe.ValorTotal = item.ValorUnitatio;

                    db.ConsertoDetalhes.Add(consDetalhe);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

            }
        }

    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Só para esclarecer você vai enviar um lista de ids a der cadastrados na base, ou vai, enviar apenas um id por clique?

Answer (score 1):

Olha, acho que isto não é possível! Poderia ser inserido em arquivos e tabelas de SQL. Mas em tabela ASP.NET, não conheço...

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você esta querendo inserir um novo registro no banco de dados, porém uma coisa que não entendi, é qual a informação que será cadastrado no banco, passando apenas um `id` ?

Pois geralmente quando passamos `id`é para recuperar um dado já cadastrado, para alterar, manipular ou apenas exibir.

No seu caso você tem que enviar um objeto com todos os valores preenchidos, valores esses que seu banco ira precisar para fazer a criação do registro.

para fazer requisição para o servidor via javascript você pode usar o `ajax`que faz requisições assincronas para o servidor.

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira.

```js
$.post(url, objetoComOsDados, function(resp){
    //Caso seu servidor retorne success, vem para aqui.
    alert("Cadastro realizado com sucesso");
})
.fail(function(error){
    //Caso de erro vem para aqui.
    console.log(error);
});
```

Já no servidor, a melhor pratica e criar um modelo com os dados que será preciso para inserir na base, e esperar este modelo como parametro da sua `Action`.

```cs
public ActionResult AddPecas(PecaModel model)
{
    //Caso queira validar o medelo antes de inserir.

    using(var db = new Contex())
    {
         db.Pecas.add(model);
         try
         {
             db.SaveChange();
             return Json(new {status = true});
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
              //Tratar o erro.
              return Json(new {status = false});
         }
    }
}
```

Lembrando que é apenas um exemplo seu controller pode fazer toda a lógica necessária para sua aplicação, como é uma chamada assincrona com java script retorne sempre um `json` como resposta.